# Split/reveal image with css translate-y on scroll

Tags: image, css

I would like to achieve the effect where one image is revealed over the other when scrolling the page.

You can see an example on [livearealabs.com](http://livearealabs.com/) (new york / seattle). Does anybody know how to create it using CSS3?

Comment: They are using CSS transforms on that site already. Unless you can't use JS I would highly recommend it since they are triggering the transform off the scroll event / animation frame

Answer (score 2):

Check out this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6QvE/2/)** to create the sliding effect.

The trick is to have one `div` rotated 60 degrees. You position it so that it covers the entire wrapper and the overflow is hidden. Then with javascript you just have to move the slice container either by changing the `left` property or by changing the `translate-X` property.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="slice" data-show="true"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20em;
    height: 10em;
}

.bg {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slice {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12em;
    left: -8em;
    width: 30em;
    height: 30em;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

JS:

```
var hidden = false;
$('.wrapper').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    if (hidden) {
        $('.slice').stop().animate({left: '-8em'}, 2000);
        hidden = false;
    } else {
        $('.slice').stop().animate({left: '-34em'}, 2000);
        hidden = true;
    }
    console.log('click end');
});
```

**Also** check out this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bx9Q/1/)** for a similar sliding effect that can be achieved with CSS only.

Comment: Here's referring specific to the SEA / NYC section

Comment: Updated my response to answer the correct question, thank @elzi